# how to raise thumbnails in ubuntu 18.04 from nautilus limiting to 4096MB maximum, to higher?

Tags: command-line, 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 the folder settings -preferences, are limiting thumbnail display to max 4096MB. How do I raise this from the terminal or command line?

Comment: Does it all have to be in the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can change it using the command line:

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences thumbnail-limit 10485760`

To reset to the default setting, issue the command

`gsettings reset org.gnome.nautilus.preferences thumbnail-limit`

Display the currently set value with:

`gsettings get org.gnome.nautilus.preferences thumbnail-limit`

See `man gsettings` for all uses of gsettings, the command line tool to manupulate GSettings.